# Android 7.0 Nougat - Checking AOT and JIT compilation in ART

Tags: jit, android-7.0-nougat, hybrid, aot, android-runtime

For some reason, I need to use only AOT compiler in ART.
According to this link:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/jit-compiler

I used four commands below
`adb root
 adb shell stop
 adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.usejit false
 adb shell start`
and emulator seemed to make a restart.

The questions are:
1- Turn off means using adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.usejit **false**.
So in order to turn on, are we using adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.usejit **true** ?

2- In the link above, there is a term Forcing Compilation. Is this an AOT compilation ? 
When I input `adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f [my-package]`
Does that mean I am forcing my App compiling all of my class ahead ?

3- Finally, how can I confirm that all of my classes have been AOT compiled ?

And how can I make sure that there is no JIT activity if question 1 above is right ?